# elementary go slow when Google Chrome is open

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using elementary OS since some months and I really like it!

Is very simple to use and is great to view. Is very fast too, except when I use Google Chrome. This happen especially when I watch something in streaming like youtube or other stream site.

I've tried to remove flash player from the system, and disable it in Chrome. I've checked for graphics drivers, but all is ok.

So what would be the problem?

Comment: How much RAM do you have

Comment: I have 4 Gb of Ram

Comment: That might not be enough.Even my laptop with 6GB RAM starts swapping and lagging when I have more than 30 tabs open.How many tabs are open

Comment: Generally 6/7 tabs

Comment: Can you install **GNOME System Monitor** from the software center.Then open it and post a screenshot of it while you are using Chrome

Comment: I have the same issue, yesterday I installed latest version, today chromium lags annoyingly. 16GB RAM, I have, before you ask. Run a lot of different  operating systems before with this machine, never encountered this lag. So I'm almost sure that it is related to ElementaryOS.

Comment: Firefox is the same...